# How to Change default homepage to my custom page without coding

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

I have installed sample data on Magento, It has default homepage set.

I have created the new page called test (**cms>pages>create page**).

When I open my localhost, the test page should appear first rather than the homepage.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Go to Navigation:-

```
Admin -> System -> Configuration -> General (Left) -> Web > Default Pages ->  CMS Home Page
```

> Select your new custom page from the drop-down.

*I hope It's helpful for you*